# Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm getting this error when I try to upload using paperclip with my rails blogging app.
Not sure what it is referring to when it says "MissingRequiredValidatorError"
I thought that by updating post_params and giving it :image it would be fine, as both create and update use post_params

```
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError in PostsController#create
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError

Extracted source (around line #30):

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
```

This is my posts_controller.rb

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
#...

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :image)
end
```

and this is my posts helper

```
module PostsHelper
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
  end
end
```

Please let me know if I can supplement extra material to help you help me.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

Starting with `Paperclip version 4.0`,  all attachments are required to include a *content_type validation*, *a file_name validation*, or to *explicitly* state that they're not going to have either.

Paperclip raises `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError` error if you do not do any of this.

In your case, you can add any of the following line to your `Post` model, **after** specifying `has_attached_file :image`

### Option 1: Validate content type

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

**-OR- another way**

```
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
```

**-OR- yet another way**

is to use *regex* for validating content type.

For example: To validate all image formats, regex expression can be specified as shown in

*[@LucasCaton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4/21898204#answer-22525202)*

### Option 2: Validate filename

```
validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /gif\Z/]
```

### Option 3: Do not validate

If for some *crazy* reason (can be *valid* but I cannot think of one right now), you do not wish to add any `content_type` validation and allow people to spoof Content-Types and receive data you weren't expecting onto your server then add the following:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

---

**Note:**

**Specify the MIME types as per your requirement within `content_type`/ `matches` options above.** I have just given a few image MIME types for you to start with.

**Reference:**

Refer to **[Paperclip: Security Validations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations)**, if you still need to verify. :)

You might also have to deal with the spoofing validation explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23846121

Comment: Validators can also be defined using the new helper style, eg.  
    `validates_attachment :image, presence: true, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] }`

Comment: @rawonstack +1 Thanks for suggesting the alternative. :) I have included that in answer after a little tweak. `presence: true` validation is not mandatory so I have excluded that part.

Comment: Paperclip will also throw "Missing Required Validator Error" in case of PDF file upload. The workaround for that is: First install the "GhostScript" and then add "application/pdf" to content-type.

Comment: I would really not recommend `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type `. As Rdocs puts it: Thanks to a report from Egor Homakov we have taken steps to prevent people from spoofing Content-Types and getting data you weren't expecting onto your server.

Comment: @user1322092 It is not recommended but it is *still valid* for someone who doesn't wish to restrict content-type. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer to point it out better.:)

Comment: My crazy reason for not doing content validation is because the attachment is not created by the users but by a system process. Paperclip is the convenience layer for S3 storage.

Answer (score 20):

Just put in your model:

```
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 5):

Need to add **validates_attachment_content_type** in Model

**Rails 3**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :avatar
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ 
end
```

**Rails 4**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: Good to know this @zire

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your post model looks like this...

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get any of these solutions to work either. I tried Paperclip 3.1, but couldn't then my app kept telling me my image file extensions weren't approved, even though they were jpg.

I finally found success with version 3.5.1.

Comment: so want to say that one can get over this problem by upgrading the version

Comment: Sort of. I started with the latest version, which right now is 4.2.1. No luck there, then again no luck with 3.1 (which I found suggested here). Someone somewhere else (I can't remember where) suggested 3.5.1, and that worked for me.