# Paperclip type validation always giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I recently updated to Paperclip 4 *(4.1.1 to be specific)* where it is necessary to validate files with `validates_attachment`. I tried it 3 ways, as the GitHub docs suggest:
`validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/`
and the 2 ways suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898204/1478394) thread.
All the cases give me an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception saying the image's content type is invalid.
I create the image using this line of code in a Grape API:
`image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(params[:data])`
The data it receives comes from Android using Apache `HttpClient`'s `MultipartEntityBuilder`

It prints the command it runs to check the mime type which is like `file -b --mime-type '/path/to/file` but when I run it, it gives me image/jpeg
The class only has 2 other lines:
`has_attached_file :image`
`attr_accessible :image`

And ideas why does it constantly fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into the same issue than you (even tried the other ways the thread suggests), and Rachel is right about the version. Paperclip 4 has some issue with spoofing. Changing it to 3.5 solved my problem.

Btw, if you still want to make it work, it seems to be the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429) ( with a workaround given )

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try doing some testing to eliminate the variables of what's going wrong here: can you try a different version of Paperclip, ~3.5? Paperclip 4 still has some bugs to be worked out (I have noticed this in my own project, it thought my normal upload had a spoofed content type).

Or: can you try creating the image a different way, just to test? The validation code you provided looks correct.