# Rails paperclip not showing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am new to paperclip, and I wanted to see how it would work. I generated a simple model Monkey and got the following:

```
rails g scaffold monkey description age:datetime
rails g paperclip monkey facepic
rake db:migrate
```

## Model

```
class Monkey< ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :facepic, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

end

## View new/edit

```
<%= form_for @monkey, :url => monkies_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :facepic %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :facepic %>
  </div>
```

## View show

```
 <%= image_tag @monkey.facepic.url %>
```

## Controller

```
@monkey = Monkey.new(monkey_params)
```

I can create new monkeys, but the show view doesn't seem to find the uploaded file. I have no error messages, except a routing error to 'missing.png'. There is no trace to the uploaded image. I am using Rails 4.1.6. What am I missing here? How do I troubleshoot this thing? The gem is installed and also imagemagick is installed.

This is what the logs say:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/facepics/original/missing.png"):
...

Started GET "/monkies/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-19 14:40:22 +0200
Processing by MonkiesController#new as HTML
  Rendered monkies/_form.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered monkies/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"monkies"} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

There is no error message displayed however when I create a new monkey... :'(

EDIT:

The Monkey model is created, but the paperclip columns remain empty.

Comment: did you added `:facepic` to your strong params ?

Comment: Do you have image in your public folder ? You might find a folder call system in your public folder and uploaded images inside it.

Comment: no image in public folder, and I didn't add it to strong params!!! I''ll try that now!

Comment: Now i get Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError with :facepic in strong params :S

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error clearly show that your images are not getting saved because path and url not specified in your `has_attached_file` block. It should be like :

```
has_attached_file :facepic, 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
  :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
  :default_url => "path to default image"
```

here default_url show image that you want if no image uploaded. For more detail you can go here http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/4.2.0/Paperclip/ClassMethods%3ahas_attached_file .

And for other error you can follow this link [Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError with Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `Paperclip version 4.0`,  all attachments are required to include a *content_type validation*, *a file_name validation*, or to *explicitly* state that they're not going to have either.

Paperclip raises `Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError` error if you do not do any of this.

In your case, you can add any of the following line to your `Post` model, **after** specifying `has_attached_file :image`

### Option 1: Validate content type

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

**-OR- another way**

```
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
```

**-OR- yet another way**

is to use *regex* for validating content type.

### Option 2: Validate filename

```
validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /gif\Z/]
```

### Option 3: Do not validate

If for some *crazy* reason (can be *valid* but I cannot think of one right now), you do not wish to add any `content_type` validation and allow people to spoof Content-Types and receive data you weren't expecting onto your server then add the following:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

---

**Note:**

**Specify the MIME types as per your requirement within `content_type`/ `matches` options above.** I have just given a few image MIME types for you to start with.

**Reference:**

Refer to **[Paperclip: Security Validations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations)**, if you still need to verify. :)

For details you can go to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4)

Comment: Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897725/papercliperrorsmissingrequiredvalidatorerror-with-rails-4

Comment: So you need to add comment with link :)

Comment: added the link in the answer. thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that my problem eventually was a bunch of things:

1. Had to add :facepic to the **strong params**
2. Had to add **validations of content type** to the model
3. Paperclip has a dependency... the **file**-command, which isn't shipped on Windows. 
   which can be downloaded here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/?source=typ_redirect

After all three, it works like a charm!

Thank you all!